# Pass outlet Data from TableViewCell to ViewController.swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

Getting error Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
while trying to pass data from tableviewcell to viewcontroller

DataCell.swift

```
 @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
```

viewcontroller.swift

```
let dataCell = DataCell()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     dataCell.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
}
```

Comment: You can't do it like that. Do you have a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
```

You have this `IBOulet` connection in a xib file or a in a stotryboard. And you are creating the cell programmatically in the view controller. When you create a cell programmatically its `IBOutlet` connections will be `nil`. Either created the `containerView` programmatically without `IBOutlet` in `DataCell` class or change the `cornerRadius` of the `containerView` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.